# update the sql table with some condition

Tags: sql, sql-update

I want to update my whole sql table except some rows. Is it possible?
I am trying with this query but not work.

```
UPDATE  `boon_rise`.`users` 
  SET  `zip` =  '0'
  WHERE  `users`.`id`
  !IN  ('5','6','7')
```

Comment: "not work" is not a problem description.

Comment: What did not work? Error messages? What `SQL`? Try `users.id NOT IN (5,6,7)`. Is `boon_rise` the name of the database and .`users` the name of the table?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you meant to use the `not in` operator:

```
UPDATE `boon_rise`.`users` 
SET    `zip` =  '0'
WHERE  `users`.`id` NOT IN ('5', '6', '7')
-- Here ------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT IN` instead of `!IN`

```
UPDATE  `boon_rise`.`users` 
  SET  `zip` =  '0'
  WHERE  `users`.`id` 
  NOT IN('5','6','7')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible :

```
Update 'boon_rize'.'users'
Set 'zip'='0'
Where 'users'.'id'
Not In ('5','6','7')
```

Good Luck.